# How does Latitude and Longitude be helpful in making the Venues/Places Recommendation system?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

I am trying to build a recommendation system which suggest the places on the basis of their ratings , reviews etc . I want to use Latitude and Longitude , but I don't know how it will be helpful in building the venues recommendation system ?

Comment: You can use Lat+Long to determine which venues are the nearest to the user.

Comment: Any more reasons?